# Install RedHat packaged Jenkins 2.73 in Openshift

Tags: jenkins, containers, openshift, upgrade, redhat

I wish to use the Openshift Jenkins RHEL7 image running latest LTS version (2.73) but RedHat only released their image with version 2.46.2:

https://access.redhat.com/containers/?tab=overview&platform=openshift#/registry.access.redhat.com/openshift3/jenkins-2-rhel7

How could I upgrade their image to use version 2.73 when I don't have access to their Dockerfile?

Has anyone encountered the same need?

Appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to wait a day or two: https://github.com/openshift/jenkins/issues/397

> I built it now. It'll make it into tonight's build.

If you want to build it yourself, you can find the Dockerfile here: https://github.com/openshift/jenkins/blob/master/2/Dockerfile.rhel7

Also, you could use the Centos version which is up-to-date and on Docker Hub: https://hub.docker.com/r/openshift/jenkins-2-centos7/